# Rails use a definition for two actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use the same definition for 2 actions?

Something like this?

```
def index2, index5
  @workgroups = Workgroup.all
  if params[:workgroup]
    @workgroup = Workgroup.find(params[:workgroup])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @workgroups }
  end
end
```

Comment: Use alias, or just call one from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three solutions

**1 Make Common method**

I would prefer this approach because in case if you want to change something...

```
def index5
  common_method_name
end

def index2
  common_method_name
end

private
def common_method_name
  # common code
end
```

**2 Alias**

```
def index5
  # your code
end

alias_method :index2, :index5
```

**3 routes**

You can route the 2 urls to the same action in `config/routes.rb`.(**source Murifox's answer**)

```
get 'controller/index5', to: 'controller#oneindex'
get 'controller/index2', to: 'controller#oneindex
```

Answer (score 2):

You can route the 2 urls to the same action.
On `config/routes.rb` do:

```
get 'controller/index5', to: 'controller#oneindex'
get 'controller/index2', to: 'controller#oneindex'
```

Comment: Reddirt, this would be defined within `config/routes.rb` if you aren't aware.